# Adding new column at the end of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to add a column at the end of a 2d array. What I've tried to do is to make a copy of the array but with the length being 1 bigger. The only problem is that that expands the rows, not the columns.

```java
// Trying to make the 2d array bigger
public static String[][] FLname = new String[1][0];
FLname = Arrays.copyOf(FLname, FLname.length + 1);

// Inserting the values
FLname[0][FLname.length - 1] = fName;
FLname[1][FLname.length - 1] = lName;
```

I end up getting a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Stream the outer array and copy inner array

1. Stream 2D array
2. map the each element(1D array) to increased column size
3. collect 1D arrays as 2D array

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int increaseColumnDelta = 2;
    String[][] input = {null, {"B"}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));
    String[][] updated = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(r -> r != null ?
                    Arrays.copyOf(r, r.length + increaseColumnDelta)
                    : new String[increaseColumnDelta])
            .toArray(String[][]::new);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(updated));
}
```

#### Same output array

If the change has to be made in same array,

1. iterate over the 2D
2. increase size of each 1D array and copy and assign back

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int increaseColumnDelta = 2;
    String[][] input = {{"A", "1"}, {"B"}};
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));
    IntStream.range(0, input.length)
            .forEach(i -> input[i] = input[i] != null ?
                    Arrays.copyOf(input[i], input[i].length
                            + increaseColumnDelta)
                    : new String[increaseColumnDelta]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(input));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the rows of this array and replace them with extended ones using [`Arrays.setAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll-T:A-java.util.function.IntFunction-) method as follows:

```java
String[][] arr = {{"one", "two"}, {"three", "four"}, {"five", "six"}};
String[] column = {"two-and-half", "four-and-half", "six-and-half"};
```

```java
// replace rows of a 2d array
Arrays.setAll(arr, i -> {
    // copy the row of the array and increase its length
    String[] row = Arrays.copyOf(arr[i], arr[i].length + 1);
    // add a new element to the end
    row[row.length - 1] = column[i];
    // return a new row
    return row;
});
```

```java
// output
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
//[one, two, two-and-half]
//[three, four, four-and-half]
//[five, six, six-and-half]
```

Answer (score 0):

*appending the column by concatenating two streams for each line*

```java
public static String[][] flNname = {…};
String[] flNameToAdd = new String[]{‹Your column data here›};
int[] n = {0};
String[][] rslt = Stream.of(flName)
        .map(s -> Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(s), Stream.of(flNameToAdd[n[0]++]))
                .toArray(String[]::new))
        .toArray(String[][]::new);
```